# Myibatis source Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: java, maven, ibatis, pom.xml

First I check out svn https://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk to mybatis project.
I´m actually trying setup a new development environment, using Apache Maven 3.0.1 and java version "1.6.0_23" When trying to build mybatis source projects within maven 3.0 . I´m getting: 
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM xxxxx  for xxxmyProjectxxxxx: Failed to [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.mybatis:mybatis-parent:pom:14-SNAPSHOT in http://192.168.1.224:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cachd in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 11

[ERROR]   The project org.mybatis:mybatis:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (E:\Source_Infomation\mybatis\pom.xml) has 1 error [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.mybatis:mybatis-parent:pom:14-SNAPSHOT in http:192.168.1.224:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath'
any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the mybatis snapshot repository in your nexus to be able to use snapshot versions of mybatis otherwise this couldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the parent pom.xml by cloning https://github.com/mybatis/parent.

Then in your MyBatis project add a `relativePath` element with a parent pom 
reference to point at the parent pom.xml, e.g.

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-parent</artifactId>
    <version>25-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
```

With Maven happy you can then compile MyBatis.

Comment: I add the relative path which points to the parent pom.xml, but it did`nt help.Laterly I import the parent project as a module of  the mybatis-3 project, everything is OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution:http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Missing-artifact-org-mybatis-mybatis-parent-pom-14-SNAPSHOT-td3650773.html

> Yep, the parent is not released yet. Check the parent out and do a
>
> mvn install -Pparent-release
>
> then try again with mybatis.